# How much do I have to reduce the factorial in Order to reach Polynomial Complexity?

Tags: optimization, computational-complexity

First of all is my first question so sorry if it will not be much clear.

Suppose that I have to find the minimal path (Travelling Saleseman Problem) in graph where I visit All the city and I return to the starting one.
The brute force algorithm has a Factorial Complexity.
So suppose that I have 50 cities to visit my algorithm will run in 50!

How much do I have to reduce that complexity always considering a factorial algorithm in order to reach a polynomial complexity? For example if my algorithm run in 20! instead then 50! and I find the optimal solution is it polynomial?

Sorry if the question is not much clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The complexity $f(n)$ of an algorithm is used to denote the number of operations performed depending on (usually) the size of the input data $n$. $50!$ is therefore not a complexity. Here, it is a fixed number, i.e. not depending on data size. Reducing the number of operations to $20!$ is not either a complexity. A polynomial complexity only makes sense again with data size as a parameter. It means that $f$ is a polynomial. Please update your question in that direction... Or delete it if you meant something totally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $50!$ and $20!$ are constants. In that 50-city example, the number of cities is always the same so the complexity will always be constant.

When people speak of polynomial/exponential/factorial time, they're **not** talking about the running time when the number of cities is fixed (50 in your example). Instead, they're talking about the time **as a function of the size of the instance**. So, to solve TSP in time that is polynomial in the number of cities, you need to find an algorithm $A$, such that the running time of $A$ when given $n$ cities is  $O(P(n))$ for some polynomial $P$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) for a formal definition of big $O$-notation.

Comment: ok, I have understood but if I fint an algorithm that solve the 50-city example in 20! will it be polynomial with respect to the 50 cities? and the proportion can be maintained also in other example, like if i have 60 cities, or more

Comment: @Not_Anonymous No, $(2n/5)!$ still grows faster than any polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T(n)$ denote the number of steps your algorithm takes for a graph on $n$ vertices. If there exists a constant $k \geq 0$ such that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{T(n)}{n^{k}} \right| < \infty,$$

then the algorithm runs in polynomial time.

Note that this criterion deals with *sufficiently large* $n$, rather than $n = 50$ or $n = 20$. Asymptotic behavior captures what happens for sufficiently large inputs, rather than your favorite test case(s).